# AWS EKS Trying to access Springboot resources over public Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-eks

I am using `AWS` + `EKS` + `Terraform` services
and deploying `SpringBoot` app with K8s.

**cluster**
[image]

---

**EC2**
[image]

---

Under Namespace **dashboard-dev**
[image]

---

**VPC**
[image]

---

**ACL**
[image]

---

**K8s status**
[image]

---

I am having separate CORS Configuration with my app

```
package com.gkonnect.portal.core.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

For some instance I did commented out above section and applied CORS to Health Check Controller
[image]

Here is how I am trying to over internet using public DNS provided on EC2 and no access
[image]

[image]

Comment: I reckon you haven't created a Load Balancer/Ingress - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html. This has nothing to do with CORS as the browser cannot reach the app at all.

Comment: Ohh, How I missed this one, Thanks @Augusto I will add ALB to this. and update you here

Comment: @Augusto thank you for your suggestions, Now I am able to connect by adding ALB. only 1 blocker is I can connect ALB to Backend (NG) but from NG I am not able to connect Springboot, showing same error `strict-policy-when-cross-origin` though I do have CORS Enabled.